# jsduck 5.3 create PHP-Doc

Tags: jsduck

Today i tried out the jsDuck 5.3 with my ExtJS project. It works really good. But I've also commented every method and class in PHP.
I've seen that JSDuck 3.11.2 can create a perfekt online documentation from PHP Files, but JSDuck 5.3 doesn't do. Is it possible to load a modul or plugin to the JSDuck 5.3 ?? Or is there an other practice to get a php-doc by jsDuck 5.3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it 3.x happened to work with PHP was that JSDuck used a bunch of simple regexes to parse the code following a doc-comment, if it encountered code it didn't understand, it just ignored it. So the reason you were able to parse PHP was an accident of poor implementation.

New JSDuck uses an actual JavaScript parser, which fails when you try to feed it something other than JavaScript.

One hackish way to make it work with PHP would be to use some pre-processor on your PHP code which strips away all the code and only leaves doc-comments - this code will then be valid JavaScipt and JSDuck would parse it.

Another option is to open up the internals of JSDuck and add a PHP parser to it.

Comment: We choose an other way, JS --> JsDuck , PHP --> YUIDoc. Thank you for help!